# Running two windows 10 OS one is 32 bit and 2nd is 64 bit on same machine will slow down my laptop?

Tags: windows

I have core i5 2nd generation pc with 320GB hard disk and 2.5 GHz processor and 4 GB of ram i want to install windows 32 and 64 bit on the same partition will it slows down the performance of pc????

Comment: You cannot install 32 and 64 bit versions of Windows in the same partition, they cannot co-exist in the same installation. You would need unique partitions, a partition/boot manager, and possibly a second hard drive to do this, and it would be two separate, distinct operating systems, applications, etc.

Comment: thank you so much my friend it helps me a lot. Now I have 32 bit windows 10 installed in the c drive what if I format c drive then install windows 10 64 bit then I have to reinstall the drivers for 64bit OS or not???

Comment: Yes, you would need to do a complete, clean installation of 64-bit Windows. In most cases the drivers will be different anyway (although many driver packages include both 32 and 64 bit versions, they are uniquely different in many cases). Moving between 32 and 64 bit OS's is no different than switching from Windows to Linux, they are uniquely different and require a clean installation and all new installations of drivers, applications, etc. However, you should be able to just copy and use your user files like normal.

Comment: To be honest, there is no reason to use a 32-bit operating system today, many applications no longer support it and most 32-bit applications will run in a 64-bit environment without issue. Making a "dual boot" scenario is not necessary and that application is typically used for different operating systems, not multiple versions/types of Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Running two operating systems on the same machine with a multi-boot configuration does only reduce the amount of free space available (wether you split your hard drive in multiple partitions, or use shenanigans to run on the same).

That may reduce the time needed to have low-freespace performance issues since the disk is filled faster.

You can execute only one at a time, so there is no other shared resource (except disk space) to 'fight for'.

Answer (score -1):

First, you can't install two OS on the same partition. You need to create two different partitions to install them.
The presence of an OS with high/low bit has nothing to do with performance. However I can't guarantee about the individual OS performance suffering due to corruption or other iasues.